# Slim: what's wrong with these data attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

In the following Slim code:

```
p = f.email_field :email,
    data: {
      toggle: 'popover',
      placement: 'right',
      trigger: 'manual',
      html: 'true'
    },
    autofocus: true,
    placeholder: 'Email address'
```

I keep getting an error that `Expected tag near toggle: 'popover'`

What am I doing wrong? Isn't this the correct way to specify data attributes in Slim?

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is wrong here, because the email field is written in one line with the p tag. This should work:

```
p
  = f.email_field :email, data: { toggle: 'popover', placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'manual', html: 'true' }, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email address'
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be it -- it's still throwing the same message. I think it's something with the data attributes array.

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you try if it would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your actual code is formatted exactly the way you have it here, then the problem could be the hard returns. In Slim, spaces and carriage returns/line feeds matter as far as how the code is interpreted.

I'd try keeping everything on a single line and see if that fixes the problem.